# powershell list permissions for user + folder

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

recently working with **powershell**.
Wonder if anybody knows some way to show allowed folders by user.

i get until this

> Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name

but i just get the groups, nothing for folder and if the user its assigned to a one folder without a group, it cannot be seen.

Im searching be able to find quickly all the permissions on a file server for one user.

Sorry for my english.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through all the folders and files and check if their permissions includes the username you're looking for.

Like so:

```
$items = Get-Childitem C:\Temp
```

This gives you an object of files and folders, which you can then pass to the GetAccessControl method
The object looks like this:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       24-05-2017     10:06                test
-a----       23-05-2017     14:55             97 test.csv
```

Now, you can use your $items object with the GetAccessControl method, like so:

```
$items.GetAccessControl() | select -ExpandProperty Access
```

Again, this will return an object, containing the NTFS file permissions of each folder in the path you specified.

Which will look like this:

```
FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : Domain\User
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Try and play around with this information, and see if you can get started on a working example, for the community to help debug :)

Please keep your replies in the original post. Sucks we cannot just comment... 
But still, yeah, what you see there, is all users/groups mentioned in the current file(in the pipeline)'s NTFS Access Control List.
Keep in mind that you can access the objects individual lines, to make your search easier.
Like so:

$Test[0].IdentityReference
Would yield "domain/user" for the first entry in the $Test array.
So you would loop through all entries using a foreach-object, or a

```
foreach($item in $test){
#Code here
# if($item.IdentityReference -eq $UserImLookingfor){Write-host "Match! -fo green" }
$i++
}
```